# ID in URL not hiding other divs

Tags: jquery, html

so Im building a script where it will hide divs based upon which ID is in the url. This is what I have so far:

```
<script>
$(function(){ 
if (document.location.href.indexOf('#aberdeen') > 0) 
$("#centralia, #chewelah, #everett, #harbour-pointe").hide();

if (document.location.href.indexOf('#centralia') > 0) 
$("#aberdeen, #chewelah, #everett, #harbour-pointe").hide();

if (document.location.href.indexOf('#chewelah') > 0) 
$("#aberdeen, #centralia, #everett, #harbour-pointe").hide();

if (document.location.href.indexOf('#everett') > 0) 
$("#aberdeen, #chewelah, #centralia, #harbour-pointe").hide();

if (document.location.href.indexOf('#harbour-pointe') > 0) 
$("#aberdeen, #chewelah, #everett, #centralia").hide();

if (document.location.href.indexOf('#') < 0)
    $(".directory").show();
});
</script>
```

However it is still showing all of them even with an id appended in the URL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's called a "hash", not an "ID".  It's located in `document.location.hash`, not `document.location.href`.

```
if (document.location.hash === '#aberdeen') {
    $("#centralia, #chewelah, #everett, #harbour-pointe").hide();
}
```

Comment: @JosephSilber: Yeah, probably.  Or make it all into one line, using jQuery's `.not`.

Answer (score 2):

try this, you can add a class to the items and use `document.location.hash`:

```
$(function(){ 
   var id = document.location.hash;
   $('.all').not(id).hide() // hide them expect the element that has an id of hash
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
if (document.location.hash.indexOf('#aberdeen') != -1) {
    $("#centralia, #chewelah, #everett, #harbour-pointe").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Javascript solutions given above, you can do this in CSS (modern browsers only):

If you give all your divs for example a `hashdisplay` class, you can have the following styles:

```
.hashdisplay { display: none; }
.hashdisplay:target { display: block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9qCYU/

WARNING!!  Only works in browsers that support the `:target` pseudo-class!

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-target